# jquery cookie plugin issue with path attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am facing issue with cookies using Jquery Cookie plugin.

In my code, i used to set cookie like this.

```
$.cookie("example", "value1");
```

I am facing problem when i override cookie value, so i changed my code as below.

```
$.cookie("example", "value2", { path: '/' });
```

If i try to get cookie value , i am getting "value1" not "value2"

```
alert( $.cookie("example") );
```

How to retrieve "value2" in a path.

Here is Jsfiddle link i tried.
http://jsfiddle.net/x99Et/1/

Thanks in advance.

Ashok.

Comment: `$.cookie().example` seem to return value2... I don't know why. `$.cookie()` is supposed to return all cookies.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert( $.cookie("example", {path: '/'}) );
```

When you do this, it returns an object. But I still don't know why.